# Not able to Login after editing login.defs, common-auth and common-password

Tags: login, password, pam

After editing login.defs, common-auth, and common-password I am unable to login.

The goal was to set password restrictions ...

I then used recovery mode and I restored the login.defs and common-auth and common-password files to their old settings, but was still not able to login. I tried adding a new user and the user was created but the new user cannot login. I think I have hosed PAM somehow, the failure is silent (will look at system logs).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by doing:

```
pam-auth-update --force
```